# Error building a gfortran compiler on Ubuntu linux

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gfortran

I'm trying to build a gfortran 5.4.0 compiler on Ubuntu Linux 18.4. I'm getting the follow error during the `make` stage:

> config.status: error: cannot find input file: `testsuite/Makefile.in'

See the [full log here](https://gitlab.com/evgenyneu/2018_summer_project_logbook/blob/master/a2019/a03/a02_star_reduction/installing_gfortran/gfortran_make_error.txt).

How do I fix it?

### My log

#### Get the source code

```
cd
mkdir gfortran
cd gfortran/
wget http://gfortran.meteodat.ch/download/x86_64/sources/releases/gcc-5.4.0.tar.xz
tar xf gcc-5.4.0.tar.xz
```

#### Build

```
cd tmp/gcc-5.4.0-source/gcc-5.4.0
mkdir gcc-build

./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd gcc-build
../configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-trunk --enable-languages=fortran
make
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing `apt-get install gfortran`?

Comment: @melpomene, good question. I need older gfortran version 5.4.0. The gfortran apt-get package gives 7.3.0.